# Implementing txtProgressBar outside of a loop

Tags: r, progress-bar, user-feedback

Say I have the following R script, where `cat` provides the user with some feedback on what is being done and `Sys.sleep` stands for the actual computations being carried on:

```
cat("Doing something\n")
Sys.sleep(1)
cat("Doing something else\n")
Sys.sleep(1)
cat("Finalizing\n")
setTxtProgressBar(pb, 3/3)
```

I would like to insert a progress bar on those `cat` calls (pun not intended) so the user has an idea of how far into the script they are. This is what I could come up so far:

```
pb <- txtProgressBar(style = 3)
cat("\nDoing something\n")
Sys.sleep(1)
setTxtProgressBar(pb, 1/3)
cat("\nDoing something else\n")
Sys.sleep(1)
setTxtProgressBar(pb, 2/3)
cat("\nFinalizing\n")
setTxtProgressBar(pb, 3/3)
```

The problem with this is that I have to manually set the progress bar updates (`1/3`, `2/3`, `3/3`), which is annoying and cumbersome, especially on longer scripts. My idea is to set those fractions as `currentScriptLine/totalScriptLines`, but I have no idea how to set these parameters. From what I've researched, R doesn't have a function to return the current or total number of lines from the script it is currently running. Or is there? How else could I tackle this problem of giving the user feedback on how far he is on the script?

Comment: Maybe another idea: If you know the number of calls in advance, you could `pb <- create_progress_bar("text"); pb$init(n)` and then `pb$step()`.